# keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\cacerts (Access is denied)

Tags: keystore, filenotfoundexception, keytool, access-denied, apex-data-loader

I am on Windows 10 with JRE8 and the command I'm using is:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin>keytool -keystore "C:\cacerts" -storepass changeit -importcert -file "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\sf.cer" -alias Symantec_Secure_Server_Class_3
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Gave the cacerts file full access to my user (eventhough I am an admin)
2. Ran keytool as System Administrator in cmd
3. Put cacerts in different locations (even tried C:\cacerts)

I keep getting the same error:

> Certificate was added to keystore keytool error:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\cacerts (Access is denied)

What else can I do to import this certificate into my cacerts file?

Answer (score 20):

Try running the command line as administrator and do it again

Answer (score 4):

Use the below command:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore test.keystore -alias testkeystore -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

the issue was that I was not giving the filename i.e. {**test.keystore**} which needs to be created as keystore file.

This will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting on another drive: D:\tmp or C:\tmp (other than root).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up switching to another computer running Windows 8 with JRE7 and it worked!

UPDATE: Windows Defender was blocking access to the cacerts file. I disabled the brick wall tool and everything is good now!

Answer (score 1):

If you are running keytool command on linux and facing similar issue, then run this keytool with sudo.

`sudo keytool -genkey -alias amq-server -keyalg RSA -keystore amq-server.ks`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are initializing certificates in Administrator mode. This can be done by right clicking over command prompt> Run as administrator(in case of Windows 8 or above). If in win 7, Go to Programs>Accessories>Command prompt>Right Click>Run as Administrator.

Then in cmd use below command(Make sure u are certificate directory):
keytool -import -file staging.cer -keystore "**%Certificate_destination %**" -storepass changeit -alias "**%Cerificate_name%**"